# Does the "this" pointer change?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I'm working with the Win32 API, and some C++ classes wrapping native Win32 API functions, and managing the window and the application itself.

So I also need the window procedure (`WndProc()`) to get and handle some messages.

To handle these messages, I access some member functions of a class with a class-instance-pointer:

```
Window* this_window = (Window*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
```

But here I have a problem, which might not be a problem, but I am not sure how the C++ standard defines this case. I'm using the `CREATESTRUCT` structure to save the `this` pointer in a member function that creates the window. The last parameter saves the `this` pointer:

```
CreateWindowExW(dwExStyle, lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y, width, height, hWndParent, hMenu, hInstance, this);
```

For this method, the `this` pointer must not change. If it does, I would work with an invalid pointer in the `WndProc()` function.

Can I trust that the `this` pointer will not change?

Comment: The question seems a bit misguided. If you are storing a pointer, it can't change unless code actually changes it. Otherwise I think there isn't enough information to address your concern.

Comment: For any given object, `this` does never change. Different `this` means different object.

Comment: `this` is not some magical pointer that doesn't obey the all the same rules.

Comment: `this` cannot change, it's used by an object to refer to itself. It's nothing more than a _"pointer to myself"_ (assuming I'm an object XD), as long as I exist, my address (`this`) remain the same.

Comment: I can't find any connection between the `lpParam` of `CreateWindowEx` and the `GWLP_USERDATA`. Are you sure there is such a connection? Where is it documented?

Comment: `this` cannot change, it cannot be `nullptr`.  Even the compiler knows this, and any code that relies on `this` being changed or `nullptr` can, and many times will be optimized out by the compiler.  Why?  Because it is nonsense code that can never occur.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I am using the lpParam to set GWLP_USERDATA with SetWindowLongPtr in the WM_NCCREATE/WM_CREATE message.

Comment: While an [mre] might not be needed for this specific question (which has been answered in comments above, in that one objects `this` pointer can't change) it might still be useful to avoid confusion. Or skip the code at all, since this is more or a conceptual question, and not really code-related.

Comment: @rwCapt well, then you have to ensure, that the lifetime of your instance always exceeds the lifetime of `Window* this_window` to use it reliably.

Comment: Thanks to all. It helped me to understand it a little bit more.

Comment: Make sure to delete copy/move/assign constructors and methods. Otherwise, yes, `this` can change.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Not for the same object! those just let you copy one object into a different one

Comment: @user253751 Yes, but if you save `this`, then it is also copied by the default copy/move and will give you the same result as if "this" was effectively changed (which is the case in the above question). https://onlinegdb.com/Ai6q4RZog

Answer (score 1):

The pointer will not change, but you do have to make sure that it points at the correct thing to begin with.

The `lpParam` parameter of `CreateWindowEx()` is a `void*`, so it will take *any* pointer as-is. However, your `WndProc()` is expecting a `Window*` pointer specifically, so make sure you are storing a `Window*` pointer to begin with.

For instance, if you are calling `CreateWindowEx()` inside a class `MyWindow` that derives from `Window`, then `this` will be `MyWindow*` not `Window*`.  Depending on how `MyWindow` is actually implemented, a `Window*` pointer and a `MyWindow*` pointer that point to the same *`MyWindow` object* are not guaranteed to point at the same *memory address*.  So, you should upcast `this` from `MyWindow*` to `Window*` before passing it to `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_USERDATA)`, eg:

```
CreateWindowExW(..., static_cast<Window*>(this));
```

Or:

```
CreateWindowExW(..., this);
...
Window* this_window = static_cast<MyWindow*>(pcs->lpCreateParams);
SetWindowLongPtr(..., reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(this_window));
...
```